# concise javascript to get all unique values for a particular key

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js, underscore.js

I have a javascript array, and I want to get all unique values for a particular key. I have implemented it using underscore like this:

```
var v = { "b" : 2 };
var w = { "a" : 4, "b" : 2 };
var x = { "a" : 1, "b" : 2 };
var y = { "a" : 4, "b" : 2, "c" : 3 };
var z = { "a" : null, "b" : 2, "c" : 3 };
var data = [v,w,x,y,z];

// this is the part I'd like to make more concise
var keys = _.map(data,function(d) { return d.a; });
keys = _.unique(keys);
keys = _.reject(keys, function(k) { return _.isUndefined(k) || _.isNull(k)});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Gc4tJ/

It seems like there should be a more compact way to do this, but I can't quite figure out if there is. I don't need to use underscore here either. I'm using d3 but couldn't quite figure out a simpler way to do this in d3 either.

Comment: One tiny improvement is to use pluck: `_.pluck(data, 'a')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simplify by using the [`pluck`](http://underscorejs.org/#pluck) method. Also, the `reject` thing could be shortened by using either [`compact`](http://underscorejs.org/#compact) or [`without`](http://underscorejs.org/#without).

```
var values = _.chain(data).pluck("a").unique().compact().value();
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me get this compacted

Answer (score 1):

If you're ok with the a property being cast to a string, you can use d3.set. Without underscore, correctly checking for null and undefined is a little cumbersome, it might make sense to create your own function to do so:

```
keys = d3.set(
    data.map(function(d){ return d.a; })
        .filter(function(d){  return (typeof d !== "undefined") ? d !== null : false })
    ).values();
```

Just using vanilla javascript is a little longer, but doesn't cast to strings:

```
keys = data.map(function(d){ return d.a; })
     .reduce(function(p, v){ return p.indexOf(v) == -1 ? p.concat(v) : p; }, [])
     .filter(function(d){  return (typeof d !== "undefined") ? d !== null : false });
```

As Bergi points out, you could also use [chaining](http://underscorejs.org/#chaining) to make your underscore code more concise.

For more underscore/javascript/d3 comparisons, Mike Bostock updated a [gist](https://gist.github.com/mbostock/3934356) with equivalents between them a few weeks ago. I've [added](https://gist.github.com/1wheel/5880780) a few more, but they start getting pretty tricky/harder to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Could you filter on truthy values?

```
_.uniq(data.map(d => d.a).filter(d => d))
```